# Spark Scala withColumn getItem

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have some prototype scala code using

```
.withColumn("column_name_dod", $"column_name".getItem("dod"))
```

I know the meaning of `withColumn`, but I don't know `getItem`

Comment: `getItem` is used to access the elements in an array column or get a value by key from a map type column. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@getItem(key:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: specially get element in an array using index or name of the attribute e.g.$"column_name".getItem(0)

Answer (score 0):

The function `getItem()` returns the corresponding value with the key `dod` which comes under the column `column_name`

So, if you have dataframe

| id | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"dod": 4, "x": 10} |
| 2 | {"dod": 6, "x": 20} |

Then, after the operation you mentioned, you would get:

| id | column_name | column_name_dod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"dod": 4, "x": 10} | 4 |
| 2 | {"dod": 6, "x": 20} | 6 |